# MongoDB Aggregate Regex Match or Full Text Search returns whole Document

Tags: regex, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Ex. Record

```
[
  {
  "_id": "5528cfd2e71144e020cb6494",
  "__v": 11,
  "Product": [
                {
                "_id": "5528cfd2e71144e020cb6495",
                "isFav": true,
                "quantity": 27,
                "price": 148,
                "description": "100g",
                "brand": "JaldiLa",
                "name": "Grapes",
                "sku": "GRP"
                },
                {
                "_id": "552963ed63d867b81e18d357",
                "isFav": false,
                "quantity": 13,
                "price": 290,
                "description": "100g",
                "brand": "JaldiLa",
                "name": "Apple",
                "sku": "APL"
                }
            ],
  "brands": [
            "Whole Foods",
            "Costco",
            "Bee's",
            "Masons"
            ],
  "sku": "FRT",
  "name": "Fruits"
  }
]
```

My Mongoose function to return query from AngularJS(http://localhost:8080/api/search?s=)

```
router.route('/search')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Dept.aggregate(
                { $match: { $text: { $search: req.query.s } } }, 
                { $project : { name : 1, _id : 1,  'Product.name' : 1, 'Product._id' : 1} },
                { $unwind : "$Product" },
                { $group : {
                    _id : "$_id",
                    Category : { $addToSet : "$name"},
                    Product : { $push : "$Product"}
                }}
        )
    });
```

RESULT: e.g. http://localhost:8080/api/search?s=Apple / Grape / Carrot, result is same for all.

```
[
  {
  "_id": "5528cfd2e71144e020cb6494",
  "Category": ["Fruits"],
  "Product": [
              {
              "_id": "5528cfd2e71144e020cb6495",
              "name": "Grapes"
              },
              {
              "_id": "552963ed63d867b81e18d357",
              "name": "Apple"
              },
              {
              "_id": "552e61920c530fb848c61510",
              "name": "Carrots"
              }
            ]
  }
]
```

PROBLEM: On a query of "apple", it returns all objects within Product instead of just "grapes", i think maybe putting match after unwind would do the trick or $regex case

WHAT I WANT: e.g. for a searchString of "grape"
Also I want it to start sending results as soon as I send in the first two letters of my query.

```
[{
  "_id": ["5528cfd2e71144e020cb6494"], //I want this in array as it messes my loop up
  "Category": "Fruits", //Yes I do not want this in array like I'm getting in my resutls
  "Product": [{
              "_id": "5528cfd2e71144e020cb6495",
              "name": "Grapes"
              }]
}]
```

Thanks for being patient.

Comment: UPDATE: { $match : { '$idol.name' : new RegExp(query, 'gi') } } gives a key by key query , ONLY thing remains now is specific object only return

Comment: UPDATE: { $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" }, name: 1 } }, { $limit: 1 } It returns the whole document

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I dont know if can rip anything else off the question, i tried my best..could you please let me know if any required info is missing. @JonathanMee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following aggregation pipeline:

```
var search = "apple",
    pipeline = [
        {
            "$match": {
                "Product.name": { "$regex": search, "$options": "i" }  
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind": "$Product"
        },
        {
            "$match": {
                "Product.name": { "$regex": search, "$options": "i" }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "Category": "$name",
                "Product._id": 1,
                "Product.name": 1
            }
        }
    ];

    db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

With the above sample document and a regex (case-insensitive) search for "apple" on the `name` field of the Product array, the above aggregation pipeline produces the result:

**Output**:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "5528cfd2e71144e020cb6494",
            "Product" : {
                "_id" : "552963ed63d867b81e18d357",
                "name" : "Apple"
            },
            "Category" : "Fruits"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so $group is not neccessary..wish I knew that earlier..could've saved me 3 days

Comment: @AyushSingh It's necessary when you want to group documents based on certain fields and combine their values. In your case, you didn't need any grouping but rather some projection on some fields based on a certain condition.